# Border outline for parent div of selected event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to give a border outline around **parent div** of selected `event.target`.

```js
// when we're about to show the context menu, show our own instead
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
  // Avoid the real one if this is the link
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("sim-row-edit")) {
   console.log("right click identified");
$(event.target).parent().css("border", "1px solid red");
    event.preventDefault();
 clicked_link = $(event.target).text();
 clicked_url = $(event.target).attr("href");
 clicked_id = $(event.target).attr("id");
 
 
 
 //alert(clicked_link);
    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").show(100).
    css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
  }
});

// hide our context menu when the document is clicked
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
  //alert("hii2");
  // This is the triggered action name
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
    case "first":
     // console.log("first");
    console.log("-----");
    console.log(clicked_link);
    console.log(clicked_url);
    console.log(clicked_id);
    
 
   //console.log($(this).parent().text());
      break;
    case "second":
      console.log("second");
      break;
    case "third":
      console.log("third");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4679BD;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div>
  Lorem Ipsum..
  
  <a href="http://goo.com" id="id-goo" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link">right click on me and my parent div should get a border line</a>
  </div>
   
   <div class="sim-row-edit">
   <a href="http://voo.com" id="id-voo"  data-type="link">voo</a>
   </div>
   
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action = "first">Get Name</li>
  <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it something like this your looking for ` $(event.target).css("border","1px solid #000")`

Comment: yes but not for `event.target` but for its parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$(event.target).parent().addClass("selected");
```

to add border to the parent.

Add this css in your stylesheet

```
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

To remove the border you can use

```
// hide our context menu when the document is clicked
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: worked, thanks a lot and what will be the line to clone the selected div

Comment: and if i click anywhere else, how to hide back this borderline ?

Comment: perfect thanks, if you can guide me on how to clone the div, that would be of great help

Comment: You can read about cloning element here: [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.closest(selector)` method of `jQuery` to find parent div

```
$(event.target).closest('div').css("border", "1px solid red")
```